# Разрыв строки при нажатии на Enter

Tags: jquery

Форма работает на Ajax и отправка данных происходит при нажатии на Enter

```
$("#txt_post").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 13){
        document.getElementById('txt_post').value += '\r\n';
        return;
    }

if(event.keyCode == 13){
        send();
    }
});
```

Всё по плану. Отправка происходит при нажатии на Enter. Перевод строки добавляется при нажатии на CTRL+ENTER. Но проблема заключается в следующим:

Есть следующий текст(пример):

> Повседневная практика показывает, что новая модель организационной
> деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем
> массового участия. Задача организации, в особенности же начало
> повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет за собой процесс
> внедрения и модернизации модели развития. Идейные соображения высшего
> порядка, а также новая модель организационной деятельности
> представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития

Если курсор находится в конце, то всё нормально, а если где-то в тексте, то при нажатии на Enter, в том месте где был курсор добавляется разрыв строки

> Повседневная практика показывает, что новая модель организационной
> деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем
> массового участия. Задача организации, в особенности же начало
> повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет  за собой процесс
>
> внедрения и модернизации модели развития. Идейные соображения высшего
> порядка, а также новая модель организационной деятельности
> представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки форм развития

Как это исправить?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: $("#txt_post").keypress(function(event){
        if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 13){
            document.getElementById('txt_post').value += '\r\n';
        }

        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            send();
        }
    });

Я пробывал так. Но это производит новую проблему, а именно не выполняется первая часть — не добавляется перевод строки нажатием CTRL+Enter